# Mediamuxer produces corrupted video when samples are written in batch

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I'm trying to use Android's MediaMuxer and MediaCodec to produce MP4 videos.

If I drain frames from the codec directly to the muxer by calling writeSampleData(), everything works fine and the correct video is produced.

But if I try to first store these frames on an array and decide later to send them to the muxer, I'm unable to produce a working video, even if the presentation timestamps are correct.

For some reason, it seem that the mediamuxer output depends not only on the presentation timestamps, but also on the actual time "writeSampleData" is called, although it's my understanding that having the correct timestamps should be enough.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: For an example of storing video frames in memory and writing them out later, see Grafika's "continuous capture" Activity -- https://github.com/google/grafika . Are you preserving the flags?

Comment: I'm combining the required information  (bytebuffer, trackId and bufferInfo + flags) on a custom object. This object is sent to the muxer via a queue. If a fetch from the queue and write immediately to the muxer, it works. If I again store these object in an array and later proceed with the writeSampleData, it fails. I'll take a look at grafika's code.

Comment: Are you sending all of the frames through? Is the first frame a sync frame? The next thing to do would be to run it in "immediate" and "deferred" modes, and then compare the hex dumps of the output to see if there is an obvious difference. (Ideally with a fixed source, like GLES output, or just have two MediaMuxers, and send the same data twice, once immediately and once deferred.) Watch for complaints in logcat from MediaMuxer that only appear in "deferred" mode.

Comment: One simple test I did was to introduce a delay while writing the frames. This was enough to create an unplayable file.

Comment: And yes, the first frame is a sync frame.

Comment: You can feed frames to MediaCodec / MediaMuxer as slowly or quickly as you want, and it should have no effect. The Grafika example demonstrates total separation of video encoding from file generation (I've never tried adding pauses to the file write process, but nothing in MediaMuxer appears to care what time it is). If adding a small delay is introducing problems, you need to look for races and overruns in your code. Using a GLES video frame generator to create a consistent input sequence might help spot the difference in behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks [mstorsjo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115956/mstorsjo) and [fadden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden). I had actually a combination of errors which didn't allow me to understand what was really going on. Both your questions led me to the correct code and the conviction that using writeSampleData() was *not* time sensitive.

Yes, I was getting the wrong buffers at the first time. The problem was not initially noticeable because the muxer was writing the frames before the buffers got rewritten. When I introduced the delays and decided to duplicate the buffers contents, I hit another issue (basically a race condition) and concluded it was not the case.

What this code does (for the [SmartPolicing](https://igarape.org.br/en/smart-policing/) project) is capture video and audio to create a MP4 file. I could use MediaRecorder (this was the initial solution), but we also wanted to intercep the frames and stream the video via web, so we dropped the MediaRecorder and created a custom solution.

Now it is running smoothly. Thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you actually store the complete data for the frames to be written, not only the buffer indices?

Comment: Yes. I've even duplicated in a new byte[] and wrapped it as a bytebuffer.